# How css and javascript can work together?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made some bubbles moving randomly by dynamically adding css styles with the help of javascript.
Here I have used a    addElement    method to add multiple    div    blocks.
Now when I create a new element inside the body and try to style with css without javaScript under `<style>` element it doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   box-shadow:0 0 10px #0000e6;
      -webkit-transition: 5s linear;
    }
    .box:hover {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
   background-color:red;
      
    }
  }
  .next
  {
  position: absolute;
       border-radius: 10px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 20px;
       box-shadow:0 0 10px #0000e6;
    left:500px;
    top:400px;
    color:white;
  }
  </style>
 
</head>

<body bgcolor="black" onload="bbbl()">

<h2 class="next">Next</h2>

 <script>



function getRandom(max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - 0) + 0;
}

function moveRandom(){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.left = (getRandom(window.innerWidth) -100) + 'px';
      box[i].style.top = (getRandom(window.innerHeight)  -100) + 'px';
    }
}

function bbbl() {

  for (i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div')
    el.classList.add('box')
    el.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    el.style.opacity = "0.9";
    document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.childNodes[0])

    moveRandom()
  }
 }  

bbbl()
setInterval(moveRandom, 5000)

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have a stray `}` in your style - just above `.next` - remove it and it works just fine

Comment: OH!!!...I missed that.Thanks a lot!!.

Comment: Get use to adding semicolons after each line....Javascript isn't like Swift, a semicolon terminates the line.  Some browsers might struggle to interpret the code without a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      box-shadow:0 0 10px #0000e6;
      -webkit-transition: 5s linear;
    }
    .box:hover {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      background-color:red;

    }
  } <<<<<<<<<<<<< delete
  .next
  {
  position: absolute;
       border-radius: 10px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 20px;
       box-shadow:0 0 10px #0000e6;
       left:500px;
       top:400px;
       color:white;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="black" onload="bbbl()">

<h2 class="next">Next</h2>

 <script>



function getRandom(max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - 0) + 0;
}

function moveRandom(){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.left = (getRandom(window.innerWidth) -100) + 'px';
      box[i].style.top = (getRandom(window.innerHeight)  -100) + 'px';
    }
}

function bbbl() {

  for (i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div')
    el.classList.add('box')
    el.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    el.style.opacity = "0.9";
    document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.childNodes[0])

    moveRandom()
  }
 }  

bbbl()
setInterval(moveRandom, 5000)

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What did you fix?